# Can't compile Angular project

Tags: angular, angular-cli, node-modules

I created project on my laptop and it workes fine, I cloned it from git repository to my PC and when I try to compile it, it throws strange error:

```
ERROR in Could not resolve module E:/C

webpack: Failed to compile.
```

I updated `Angular CLI` version, tryed to remove `node_modiles` folder and install again, but it didn't help. How can I fix this error?

**Update:**

I compiled my project using `ng s -aot`. I still don't know why It can't compile with simple `ng s` command and what does this error mean.

Comment: Sounds like you suffered from what I experienced. Maybe this issue will help you. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4913

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this error because I have `#` in the path to the project. After removing `#` project compiled correctly.